# function pointer as structure member

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

```
    void TestOperation_Init(const void *Ptr)        
     {
        /*do something*/
     }

    struct FeatureStruct 
    {
        const Select *S;
        void (*Init)(const void *Ptr);
    };

    sturct Cnf
    {
        const FeatureStruct *Feature;
    };


    const Cnf Cnf_1[0]=
    {
       &FeatureStruct_1[0],
    };

    const FeatureStruct FeatureStruct_1[0]=
    {
    (Select*)&TestStruct,
    TestOperation_Init,
    };

    const Cnf *CnfPtr;

   void Main_Init(const Cnf *MainCnfPtr)
   {
    CnfPtr=MainCnfPtr;
    CnfPtr->Feature->Init(CnfPtr->Feature->S);
   }
```

User will call

```
Main_Init(&Cnf_1[0]);
```

Now if I want to access member of feature struct

I write it like this

```
CnfPtr->Feature->Init(CnfPtr->Feature->S);
```

But compiler gives error at "Feature->Init" and Feature->S" that left side of -> is not struct

If I write like this

```
CnfPtr->Feature.Init(CnfPtr->Feature.S);
```

It works and gives not error.

My question is,
What is correct way to access function pointer which is memeber of another structure ?
Because Feature is pointer to the structure and it points to "Init" function pointer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Sturct`, really? I can see at least 4 trivial errors with the naked eye.

Comment: Code you have given doesn't behave as you have described. Please post *complete*, minimal version of your code, so that it can be tested by others.

Comment: Sorry, Now onward I will try to write correct syntax. I have just wrote the logic.  I have provided more details.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the below code snippet which will show how to access function pointers within structure.Please make a note that C is case sensitive. In your code you tend to just ignore it.

Question:

> What is correct way to access function pointer which is memeber of
>   another structure ?

```
    struct FeatureStruct 
    {
    void (*Init)();
    };

    struct Cnf
    {
     struct FeatureStruct *Feature;
    };

void func()
{
    printf("Hi\n");
}


int main(void) {
    struct Cnf *CnfPtr;
    CnfPtr = malloc(sizeof(struct Cnf));
    CnfPtr->Feature = malloc(sizeof(struct FeatureStruct));
    CnfPtr->Feature->Init = func;/* Initialize your pointer */
    CnfPtr->Feature->Init();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think, I do not need malloc. I have updated my code.

Comment: @Sam11 I can't make out what has changed here but if you have a pointer to your structure then you need to allocate memory for it